# Matplotlib just giving error messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to use Matplotlib. I have used it here at work before and it ran just fine. I am using the IDLE environ and I read on the Matplotlib website that interactive mode does not work in IDLE, but that should not matter in this case. Also, the library seems to importing just fine:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib as plt
>>> x = np.arange(0,3 * np.pi, 0.1)
>>> y = np.sin(x) 
>>> plt.plot(x,y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
  plt.plot(x,y)
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plot'

>>> plt.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
  plt.show(x,y)
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```