# Python Pandas Series if else box plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have alot of data in a dictionary format and I am attempting to use pandas print a string based on an IF ELSE statement. For my example ill make up some data in dict and covert to Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1.5,2.8,9.3],b=[7.2,3.3,4.9],c=[13.1,4.9,15.9],d=[1.1,1.9,2.9]))

df
```

This returns:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1.5 7.2 13.1 1.1
1   2.8 3.3 4.9 1.9
2   9.3 4.9 15.9 2.9
```

My IF ELSE statement:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if (df[col] < 4).any():
        print('Zone %s does not make setpoint' % col)
    else:
        print('Zone %s is Normal' % col)
```

Returns:

```
Zone a does not make setpoint
Zone b does not make setpoint
Zone c is Normal
Zone d does not make setpoint
```

But now I want to add in an extra to create a box plot where I am not making setpoint and also average the data frame where it is making setpoint. I know this is pandas series, but can `pandas.Series.plot.box()` be used?

This is my IF ELSE statement that I am using in a function with `df.apply(lamba x:)` and I am stuck trying to get the box box plot to work in pandas series... Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _print(x):
    if (x < 4).any():
        print('Zone %s does not make setpoint' % x.name)
        df.boxplot()
        plt.show()
    else:
        print('Zone %s is Normal' % x.name)
        print('The average is %s' % x.mean())
```

Im getting an error when I am calling `df.apply(lambda x: _print(x))`

> `module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'show'`

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error ([according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139163/matplotlib-just-giving-error-messages) was it fixed when you add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` or not )? 
If yes can you please update your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can call `pandas.Series.plot.box()` like `df['a'].plot.box()` to get the boxplot of your column `a`.

To fit with your question I would have done this:

```
def _print(x):
    if (x < 4).any():
        print('Zone %s does not make setpoint' % x.name)
        df[x.name].plot.box() #call x.name to retrieve the column name
        plt.show()
        print(df[x.name].describe())
    else:
        print('Zone %s is Normal' % x.name)
        print('The average is %s' % x.mean())
    print('---')

df.apply(lambda x: _print(x))
```

Illustrated below extract of the output for `zone B` and `zone C`.

[image]

Note that you can add `.describe()` to get the boxplot and other stats description (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)).

Nevertheless I would have approach the problem differently, according to the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48874941/3941704).

---

**Another solution**

You can filter your dataframe to split into make setpoint or not:

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: not (x < 4).any())
```

Then plot the boxes on the one that doesn't make the set point.
Plot all in a figure if the variation is not too large, and if there is not so many zones:

```
df[s[~s].index].boxplot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or separate them:

```
for col in s[~s].index:
    df[col].plot.box()
    plt.show()
```

In both case get the statistics in a `dataframe`:

```
statdf = df[s[~s].index].describe()
print(statdf)

              a         b         d
count  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000
mean   4.533333  5.133333  1.966667
std    4.178915  1.960442  0.901850
min    1.500000  3.300000  1.100000
25%    2.150000  4.100000  1.500000
50%    2.800000  4.900000  1.900000
75%    6.050000  6.050000  2.400000
max    9.300000  7.200000  2.900000
```

This way you can get the stat (say '`mean`' for instance) with `statdf.loc['mean']`.

If you want to print the mean of the one that does make the set point:

```
print(df[s[s].index].mean())

c    11.3
Name: mean, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if that is what you are looking for, but... you are asking :

> I want to add in an extra to create a box plot

You are trying this using... `df.Series.plot.box()`, which outputs the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Series'`.

Try using instead [`df.boxplot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html), which will then show at each `plt.show()` call...

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I updated the post where the box plot is only ran on one part of the if else statement based on the condition but Im still getting an error. Do you have any ideas to get this to work? Thanks